# Unable to setState regardless of making setState synchronous

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, setstate

I am learning about how to use synchronous `setState` but it is not working for my project. I want to update the state after I get the `listingInfo` from Axios but it does not work, the `res.data`, however, is working fine

```
class ListingItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listingInfo: {},
      open: false,
    };
    this.getListingData(this.props.itemId);
  }

  setStateSynchronous(stateUpdate) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(stateUpdate, () => resolve());
    });
  }

  getListingData = async (item_id) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/items/${item_id}`);
      console.log(res.data);//it's working
      await this.setStateSynchronous({ listingInfo: res.data });
      // this.setState({
      //   listingInfo: res.data,
      // });
      
      console.log(this.state.listingInfo);//no result
    } catch (err) {
      setAlert('Fail to obtain listings', 'error');
    }
  };
```

I would be really grateful for your help!

Comment: We can't control the **React**'s `setState` behavior. What are you trying to achieve by setting state synchronously BTW? You can use [conditional-rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) approach to hide UI component until API data is fetched.

Comment: @PrathapReddy I just want to make the setState work because currently, it is not working at all hahaha

Comment: The line commented in your should work. But you will not see the data immediately after `setState` since the `state` updates are asynchronous. Component will rerender data in UI if you are using that data in return block. Isn't it working for you?

Comment: Yes, it is already working. Thank you so much! I use the conditional rendering and commented area as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PrathapReddy! I used conditional rendering to prevent the data from rendering before the `setState` is done. I added this line of code on the rendering part:

```
render() {
    if (Object.keys(this.state.listingInfo).length === 0) {
      return (
        <div>
          Loading
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return //put what you want to initially render here
    }
}
```

Also, there is no need to modify the `setState`, the normal `setState` will do. Hope this is useful!